# Extract standard errors from glm

Tags: r, extract, glm, standard-error

I did a `glm` and I just want to extract the standard errors of each coefficient. I saw on the internet the function `se.coef()` but it doesn't work, it returns *`"Error: could not find function "se.coef""`*.

Comment: Might help to put up some data and example code.

Answer (score 41):

The information you're after is stored in the `coefficients` object returned by `summary()`. You can extract it thusly: `summary(glm.D93)$coefficients[, 2]`

```
#Example from ?glm
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family=poisson())

#coefficients has the data of interest
> summary(glm.D93)$coefficients
                 Estimate Std. Error       z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  3.044522e+00  0.1708987  1.781478e+01 5.426767e-71
outcome2    -4.542553e-01  0.2021708 -2.246889e+00 2.464711e-02
outcome3    -2.929871e-01  0.1927423 -1.520097e+00 1.284865e-01
treatment2   1.337909e-15  0.2000000  6.689547e-15 1.000000e+00
treatment3   1.421085e-15  0.2000000  7.105427e-15 1.000000e+00

#So extract the second column
> summary(glm.D93)$coefficients[, 2]
(Intercept)    outcome2    outcome3  treatment2  treatment3 
  0.1708987   0.2021708   0.1927423   0.2000000   0.2000000
```

Take a look at `names(summary(glm.D93))` for a quick review of everything that is returned. More details can be found by checking out `summary.glm` if you want to see the specific calculations that are going on, though that level of detail probably is not needed every time, unless you <3 statistics.

Comment: Are the standard errors stored within the `glm.D93` object? I couldn't eyeball it using `str()`. Or does `summary()` explicitly calculate the errors?

Comment: @mindless.panda - AFAIK they are calculated directly by `summary.glm`. If you type the function into your console sans `()` and then scroll down about 25 lines, you'll see where it's calculated.

Answer (score 31):

Another way:

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(glm.D93)))
```

Comment: This is beautiful - pure and simple.

Answer (score 6):

se.coef() actually does work. But it's not in the base package: it's in the {arm} package: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/arm/docs/se.ranef